# Custom Scrollbars to Replace Default

Tags: jquery, html, firefox, scrollbars

Does anyone know of a jQuery plugin for instance that will replace the default main scrollbar of a webpage with a custom one?  Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try [jScrollPane](http://jscrollpane.kelvinluck.com/)

Comment: Thank you very much.  I shall try using this plugin in my site.